# IIS 10 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:xxxxx

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm receiving this error on my workstation when I try to launch an Asp.Net Classic site in IIS.

I'm running windows 10 and I have more then 20 Asp.net Classic site on IIS. This is the only one that have this problem.

The site url is the classic path to app hosted on localhost https://localhost/appname/

It is started from today, before has always run without problem.

I've not made changes to Web.Config file

I've also tried to launch with F5 from Visual Studio 2019 but same error.

The site does not run on IISExpress.

The problem is only on my Workstation. In the production webfarm the error is not thrown.

I've tried to disable my antivirus but the problem persist.

I would like also to understand why it's trying to connect to port XXXXXX instead of 443.

This is the relevant part of my Web.Config

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15000" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="EDD379586B19136DF53C43A847814CFF4DB568B294CA6E7AED14FC257D8F6AEB" validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="A84DBA7A7659B28A57282192176B3982D216CA2D8CCB3019115B6FF6D2E02B012B7CCD24F94EAAAB4DHJKHFJFGD50E49DADA9DB056F40DD89066F0BDBDF467C" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/page404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="EDK4NetMProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
      <providers>
        <add name="EDK4NetMProvider" type="EDK4Security.EDK4NetMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />
    <sessionState cookieName="SpecialSite_SessionId" cookieSameSite="Strict" />
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" sameSite="Strict" />
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreplay@mysite.net" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="polluce.local.dmz" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
        <remove value="index.html" />
        <remove value="index.htm" />
        <remove value="Default.asp" />
        <remove value="Default.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is it really trying to connect to port XXXXX instead of an actual number? Or are you just doing that in an attempt to protect information you think might be sensitive? On your machine, are you using IIS? Or IIS Express?

Comment: Run a binding report and that's going to tell what ports are expected for this web site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html `web.config` does not contain any such information.

Comment: Check the firewall on server to confirm if it block the  443 port. Mostly this issue caused by firewall. Or you can try to disable force https rule and access it by http.

Comment: @mason No the port change randomly, yesterday was 14452

Comment: @Bruce Zhang: no other sites work without problem on 443. Also disabling firewaall the problem persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I've restarted the workstation and problem has been solved.
I don't know what is causing this behaviour.